# $1) True/false A$ is one -one if and only if $\dim V \le \dim W$. $2) A$ is onto if and only if $\dim V \ge \dim W$

Tags: linear-algebra

let  V and W  be  finite  dimesnional vectors  spaces and Let A be  a linear Transformation  from V to W .
is  Following statement is True/false

$1) A$ is  one -one if  and only  if $\dim V \le \dim W$.

$2) A$ is  onto    if     and only  if $\dim V \ge \dim W$.

My attempt : i thinks  both $1)$ and $2 )$ are  true

$1)$  dimension of  domain space  $\le$ dimension of co-domian
 space

$2)$ dimension domain space  $\ge$ dimension of co-domian space

Is  It true?

Comment: The strict if-and-only-if makes both false

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen..im not getting counter example  ????

Comment: @jasmine I have added counterexample for question 1 and some other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to both questions is false because

1) You can always construct map $A$ s.t. dim$V \leq$ dim$W$ but $A$ is not one-one.

For example, if dim$V=$ dim$W=2$ then take $A$ to be $0$ map i.e. $A(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$.

So correct statement would be,

> If $A$ is one-one then dim$V \leq$ dim $W$

2) similar reason for question 2 as well.

Please try to construct examples.

Comment: thanks u @mayuresh